# How can I differentiate a neural network with multi-outputs?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, gradient

Since we know the automatic differentiation is achieved by `tf.GradientTape` in Python, like:

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape1:
    func_1 = u(x, y)
d_fun1_dx, d_fun1_dy = tape1.gradient(func_1, [x, y])
del tape1
```

it could get the derivative of a single output neural network.

And i have an neural network with two inputs *x, y* and two outputs *f1, f2*. I want to get df1/dx, df1/dy, df2/dx, df2/dy, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to use pure tensorflow? Otherwise, I would advice you to use Keras (which uses tensorflow as backend). It handles the gradient flow for multiple inputs and outputs automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **Jacobian**, not a gradient. It is implemented in tf under `tape1.jacobian` and will return a jacobian matrix of partial derivatives.

Example from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#jacobian):

```
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  x  = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0])
  g.watch(x)
  y = x * x
jacobian = g.jacobian(y, x)
# jacobian value is [[2., 0.], [0., 4.]]
```

That being said, use of Jacobians usually requires more advanced methods, what are you planning to do with it really will guide you if you really need a Jacobian. For example if you were to simply use "gradient descent" you need to now make a decision what to do with 2 gradients per parameter. Are you going to analyse them? Are you just going to add them? If you were to add them than note that

```
(dy/dx) f(x) + (dz/dx) f(x) = (d/dx) [ f.z(x) + f.y(x) ]
```

so it is equivalent to just adding outputs and computing normal gradient. There are of course uses of Jacobians but they go much beyond typical gradient descent algorithms.